Transitioning from outdoor rated to indoor when installing cat6 for secuirty cameras
I'm hooking up exterior cameras and need to transition the wire from the external direct burial rated cable I'm using outside to a less flammable and less toxic cable inside.
(Yes, I'm aware NEC allows it for single family dwellings; this is an 300yr building without any fire breaks between floors or other modern safety stuff, so it doesn't need anything else helping a fire spread!)
Question is, where do I make this transition?  For commercial buildings NEC permits 50' of external cable run internally before transitioning, so obviously this sort of thing is done, but I can't find a damn thing about just how or where.  I can't imagine commercial buildings have patch panels every 50 feet for externally mounted cameras, and the idea of terminating the cable and using a coupler seems like it's asking for data quality issues.
I've seen bulkhead glands - essentially  couplers inside a gasket that are used to transition a cable from the outside of an enclosure cabinet to the inside, but these seem flawed in that now you've literally got an exposed ethernet jack on the outside of your house.  Plus, it means two modular terminations rather than punchdown connections, which on solid core wire is just silly.
Thoughts, ideas?

It'd help to know what your building construction is.

As far as the 50 foot rule for NEC goes: so far as I could tell NEC doesn't care how or where you make the transition; you just get to have up to 50 feet of length.
A number of years ago I used a cable that had a dual jacket for NEC compliance. It had a PE-based outer jacket for outdoor use and an inner PVC jacket, I believe it was CMR rated, for indoor use. There was a rip cord between the two jackets so that one could relatively easily strip the outer jacket on the portion of cable running inside the building. It would have been CAT5 or 5e, and I thought it was offered by Ubiquiti in their TOUGHCable family, but I can't find it now. Perhaps you can find a similar product on the market.
One assumes an outdoor direct bury cable is going to be buried -- and that it'll come out of the ground protected by a riser conduit going into some junction/pulling box. That box seems like an ideal place for a transition. One could choose a large-ish box and place a POE switch inside. This would buffer the signal electrically, give an opportunity to concentrate multiple outdoor cables onto one indoor cable, and enable conversion to in-building fiber in case distance inside the building might be long.
There also exist 110-style punch-down inline couplers, in case that's more appealing than a modular coupler.

Yeah, you'll want a box at the transition point anyway since you may very well need to have a primary protector there to satisfy NEC 805.90...
